# Can't return 200 to Stripe Webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, http-status-codes, webhooks

I am trying to test receive JSON webhooks from Stripe.

I have read:

[Stripe Webhook on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627580/stripe-webhook-on-rails)

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

They require a 200 status response in order to acknowledge receipt.

I want to solve this before moving on to dealing with the JSON.

**routes**

```
post 'webhook'       => 'web_hook#webhook'
```

**controller**

```
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_whatsupbuttercup"
class WebHookController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :webhook

  def webhook
    render status: 200
  end

end
```

With this setup, when I test a webhook, Stripe receives a 500 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to return a status use

```
head :ok
```

Instead of render.  `:ok` is the corresponding symbol for 200 but you can also use it with the status code itself.

```
head 200
```

A full list of codes and corresponding symbols can be found here...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. They actually ask for a 200 ... I updated my answer, you might want to update yours. @SteveTurczyn

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a 500 error (or any time you're confused about how your app is behaving actually) you should look in your logs. In this case you'll probably find that there's an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error because you're `render`ing but not including anything to render.