# Is it possible to set localhost as a Stripe webhook URL?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am creating a payment gateway using Stripe.

I want to set my localhost url `localhost/stripe/webhook.php` as my webhook url. Is it possible to set a localhost address as a webhook url? This will be used to create a mail service that is triggered on every successful charge in Stripe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Stripe webhooks with Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371566/using-stripe-webhooks-with-rails)

Answer (score 39):

Stripe now has an official tool, the Stripe CLI that makes this easy (but still requires installing another tool).

See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58073355/4708127) or the [official Stripe CLI docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli).

Alternatively, the another way to achieve this is with http://www.ultrahook.com which allows you to receive webhooks on localhost. This alternative will work with all webhooks, not just Stripe's

Comment: As others answered below, may want to consider the more popular [ngrok](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok) which is open-source.

Comment: ngrok has limitations per minute which make it useless for development.

Comment: ultrahook doesn't seem to return https endpoints. http endpoints aren't accepted by webhook providers like microsoft. Am i missing something here?

Comment: I switched today to `stripe`. I used to use `ngrok`, but development stopped about 4 or 5 years ago. I therefore would prefer `stripe` because of the support and it is their official tool. That said, I have not used it yet, so I do not know how it performs compared to `ngrok`.

Comment: Warning using the Stripe CLI will send events to the *localhost* **and any** *staging* webhook URLs defined in your webhook settings, simultaneously. After many misfires, Stripe will alert the account holder (normally the client) and remove the webhook URL altogether.

Answer (score 39):

There's now another option: you can now use [the Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) to seamlessly test webhooks locally without the need for a 3rd party tool.

In this case you would just do [something like this](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli#forward-events) to plumb your Stripe events through to your local webhook handler code:

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost/stripe/webhook.php
```

Comment: It may not be 3rd party, but you do need to install another tool which is unfortunate. However this should be the recommended answer now.

Comment: If you need to debug webhooks, append `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm` to the url and wrap it in quotes. But be aware, stripe webhooks time out pretty fast.

Comment: In case you're working with `Vue/Laravel` -> Follow this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4Jz9UPAyI0
you don't need to use `vue-stripe` for it but it does a good job explaining which `routes` to create and how `webhooks` work.

Answer (score 32):

How to use ngrok and set up Stripe Webhooks url

[Source Link](http://www.thecodedeveloper.com/run-stripe-webhooks-url-from-localhost/)

1. First Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) and extract it on your computer
2. Double click ngrok.exe
3. Try typing **ngrok.exe http 80** at this terminal prompt to expose port
   80
4. For example if we you have Stripe webhooks url on localhost like so
   http://localhost/stripeproject/webhook.php
5. Just specify your ngrok url as the endpoint with your webhooks
   service and you’re almost done.
6. You can set up this url
   http://f253021b.ngrok.io/stripeproject/webhook.php to send test
   webhooks to your integration’s endpoint within your account’s
   webhooks settings.

It's working fine for me.

More details [click here](http://www.thecodedeveloper.com/run-stripe-webhooks-url-from-localhost/)

Comment: Just to add, if you have custom local domain such as "server1.dev" for instance, you can pass it in ngrok as host-headers. So, if you want ngrok to point specially to server1.dev, you will issue following command: `ngrok http --host-header "server1.dev" 80`

Answer (score 5):

Try with stripe CLI:

Here you can forward events to your Localhost server.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test

Comment: please do not include link-only answers, even if it is the official docs. please be sure to copy and paste the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 4):

No this won't work. Stripe servers have to be able to contact your server to send the webhook. Stripe won't know how to contact your "localhost" . You need a web accessible address or IP address for this to work

Comment: thats what ngrok it is for. It makes your local accessible

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler, add this endpoint to your app when running locally (not in prod!):

```
const eventsSeen = new Set();

app.post("/test/simulate-stripe-webhook", async (req, res) => {
  const events = await stripe.events.list({ limit: req.query.limit || 10 });
  for (const event of events) {
    if (eventsSeen.has(event.id)) continue;
    await processStripeEvent(event);
    eventsSeen.add(event.id);
  }
  return res.status(200).end();
});
```

...where `processStripeEvent` is whatever logic your webhook triggers.

Then there's no need to manage webhooks in stripe.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send the webhooks to your local host. Look up "ngrok", when you run that it opens up a port to public internet access and provides you with a url that can access your localhost from. take this url and set it as your webhook address and finish the url by pointing it at your webhook.php file.

*** EDIT ***

This is only appropriate for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expose.sh to expose your server using a public HTTPS URL.

### Install expose.sh

For Mac or Linux, go to [Expose.sh](https://expose.sh?utm_source=stackOverflow) and copy/paste the installation code shown into a terminal.

For Windows go to [Expose.sh](https://expose.sh?utm_source=stackOverflow), download the binary and put it somewhere in your PATH.

### Expose your api to the web

Start your API server. Then run `expose <port>` where port is the port your API server is running on, like 80 or 8080.

Expose.sh will generate a random public expose.sh URL. You'll see output like

```
https://s3rh.expose.sh is forwarding to localhost:80
http://s3rh.expose.sh is forwarding to localhost:80
```

Then you can get Stripe to use the public HTTPS URL, which will forward to localhost.
I've written a full guide [here](https://expose.sh/blog/2020/07/09/validate-webhooks-on-localhost?utm_source=stackOverflow)

Disclaimer: I built expose.sh

Answer (score 0):

Like Matt said, you will need to put that somewhere online - preferably using https://. For your reference, I put up an example mail webhook 2 months ago here: https://github.com/pnommensen/Stripe-Webhook-Emails.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes It is Possible** to to test a strip web hook on local host
Go to this URL https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks/ and Open your End point
For i.e
https://test.com/api/StripeHook
and Now Open your Webhook atempt which is succeeded by strip and copy all json code.

Now Run your project in local host and open postman and hit https://localhost/api/StripeHook and put all copied json text in  body data of post man.

Comment: What headers do we need to set for postman to work? Its complaining no API keys provided when I send from postman.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.reliablewebhook.com VS Code extension or Web App to relay stripe webhook requests to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a stripe localhost payment using `NextJs` and https://pinggy.io totally free

1. keep you server running locally `npm run dev`
2. login to pinggy dashboard and use the provided command example: `ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:3000 a.pinggy.io`
3. use the url provided by pinggy to create a stripe webhook