# Webhooks on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, webhooks, paymill

I am creating a payment gateway using Paymill (which is comparable to Stripe). I want my website to automatically react to subscription-based billings. This is why I am considering Paymill webhooks.

I am in the testing phase and thus on localhost (XAMPP). The receiving webhook script would therefore have this URL:

```
localhost/paymill-example-php-subscriptions-master/src/Paymill/LlamaKisses/Controllers/WebhooksController.php.
```

***But is it possible at all to set a localhost address as a webhook url (and how)?***

(By the way, isn't [WebhooksController.php](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-example-php-subscriptions/blob/master/src/Paymill/LlamaKisses/Controllers/WebhooksController.php)  missing a response code line like this:

```
http_response_code(200);
```

to let the sending webhook know it succeeded and needn't retry?)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use something like ngrok to redirect a url towards your localhost or requestbin

Comment: This worked for me. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357356/is-it-possible-to-set-localhost-as-a-stripe-webhook-url"

Comment: [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels#what-are-ngrok-secure-tunnels) might be a good fit for this

Answer (score 5):

Use one of these tunneling apps:

http://john-sheehan.com/blog/a-survey-of-the-localhost-proxying-landscape

Comment: Excellent! Upvote for the information there and ngrok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Webhook Relay (https://webhookrelay.com) to create webhook forwarding tunnels or bidirectional tunnels:

```
$ relay forward -b webhook-demo http://localhost:8090/webhook
Forwarding:
https://my.webhookrelay.com/v1/webhooks/5e722a5e-f3d2-4hqec-9e9f-79f1158e4b10 -> http://localhost:8090/webhook
starting webhook relay agent..
```

Endpoints are permanent (until you delete them) and it is also possible to fan-out webhooks to more than one destination.
.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Azure Websites with a Free mode website. With that you can attach remote debugger to the Azure Website and if I am not mistaken you can do that with free tools from MS too. You can easily switch on tracing to Azure Table storage or file system and from within a webbrowser or tools look at logs. It may not be apt for you, but if you have a bit of time to play around it's quite easy.  I am logging the whole PayMill webhook message to an Azure Table .